# Remove duplicates from column in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a list of number like below in excel. Some numbers are repeated. How can I retrieve only the numbers without a duplicate in the list - in other words make the numbers that are repeated disappear..

so if I have 
100
200
100
300
600
300

All I would want to be left with is

200
600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit messy, but it may accomplish what you want (returning only items that appear once and omitting everything else). `IFERROR` is an Excel 2007+ solution - you could wrap it in `IF(ISERROR(...` to work with Excel <2007, though it will be a bit more verbose :). Enter as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX(
    $A$1:$A$6,
    SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,$A$1:$A$6)=1,ROW($A$1:$A$6),"NULL"),ROW()),
1),"")
```

This does a `COUNTIF` to find all numbers where the count is equal to 1 (duplicates will be 2+) and returns an array that looks like `{"NULL";2;"NULL";"NULL";5;"NULL"}`. Then the `SMALL` formula is used to find the kth smallest argument, where `k` in this case will be the current row (so on the first row, 1 (smallest), second row, 2 (second smallest), etc.). Any number in the array will represent the row number of values with only one match, so we put that inside of an `INDEX` formula as the row argument, with the column set to 1. You can then drag this down the entirety of your column.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using a very simple pivot table will show you distinct items (and how many of each there are, if you need that info).

Comment: This is the answer.  Pivot it, and do a count of entries.  Then filter the pivot down to those where the count is exactly 1.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Excel menu:** Select the data area, Ribbon Data tab >> Remove Duplicates

**Using formula:** use the following formula in cell B2 where your data is in A2:A7. Its an array formula so when you enter press CTRL SHIFT ENTER. Then drag down and it will only show unique records.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$7),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Data menu, point to Filter, and then click Advanced Filter.
In the Advanced Filter dialog box, click Filter the list, in place.
Select the Unique records only check box, and then click OK.

Comment: Thanks but that only gets rid of one duplicate not all duplicates. I want only the numbers which did not have a duplicate in the original list left.